# Login attempt fails on first attempt, but works after that

Tags: php

My **PHP** code for **login** works fine in my local server. It's also working on live server but always fails at **first attempt** without giving any error (validation or user verification errors).

Can't put whole code as it's on a live server. Found many questions on web with same problem (even on stackOverflow) but without any answwer.

Please help!

Login Page:

```
<form class="form-signin" id="form-signin" action="./" name="LoginForm" role="form">

        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please Sign In</h2>

        <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"></span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username" autofocus>
        </div>

        <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"></span>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"  >
        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" id="signinBtn" data-loading-text="Verifying...">Sign in</button>
      </form>
```

javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#form-signin").submit(function(){  // actions when form is submitted
        $("#msg").hide();           //hide the danger alert         
        var btn = $("#signinBtn");          
        btn.button('loading');       // change sign-in button state to loading till ajax complete
        username = $("#username").val();
        password = $("#password").val();
        if ((username==null || username=="") || (password==null || password=="") )  // i.e if any of the username password field is empty
        {
         $("#msg").html("Please Fill the form completely");
         btn.button('reset');
         $("#form-signin").effect('shake');  // shake effect --> needs jquery.ui
         $("#msg").show(200);
          return false;
        }
        else{
          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "verify.php",
            data: "username="+username+"&password="+password,
            success: function(verified){
                // if user is verified redirect according to the level of user
               if(verified == 'true1')  
                window.location = "http://example.com/page1.php";
               else if(verified == 'true2')
                window.location = "http://example.com/page2.php";
               else if(verified == 'true3')
                window.location = "http://example.com/page3.php";
               else if(verified == 'false')
               {
                //else display error
                $("#msg").html("<strong>Invalid</strong> username password combo!");
                $("#form-signin").effect('shake');
                $("#msg").show(200);
                btn.button('reset');
               }
            }
          });
          return false;
        }
      });  // .submit function ends
  }); //.ready function ends
```

PHP code:

```
  <?php
include("DataBaseLogin.php");
session_start();
$user = $_POST["username"];
$pass = $_POST["password"];

$user = htmlspecialchars($user);
$pass = htmlspecialchars($pass);
$user = mysql_real_escape_string($user, $db_handle);
$pass = mysql_real_escape_string($pass, $db_handle);

if ($db_found)
 {
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user_table WHERE uname = '$user' AND pword = '$pass'"); 
$resultArray=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
 if($resultArray['uname']==$user && $resultArray['pword']==$pass) 
 { 
  //If user verified
  $_SESSION['login'] = "1";
  $_SESSION["current_user"]=$user;
  $_SESSION['Level'] = $resultArray['Level'];
  $Level = $_SESSION['Level'];

  if($Level==1)
  echo 'true1';
  else
  if($Level==2)
  echo 'true2';
  else if($Level==3)
  echo 'true3';
 } 
 else 
 { 
  $_SESSION['login'] = "";
  echo 'false';
  mysql_close($db_handle);
  }
}

else
{
echo "db not found";
mysql_close($db_handle);
}
?>
```

code for page1 //after verification

```
<?PHP
session_start();
include("DataBaseLogin.php");
if (!(isset($_SESSION['login']) && $_SESSION['login'] != ''))
 {
 header ("Location: index.php");
 }
else if($_SESSION['Level'] !=1)
 die("You are not allowed on this page");
?>
```

now html code for page1 to show if user is allowed.

Comment: please post (the relevant parts of) your code, or make a new code which behaves the same and does nothing else than reproducing the problem

Comment: Ok. Posting the code.

Comment: whats in `DataBaseLogin.php`

Comment: It is for login to backend database.

Comment: You need to trace it in your browser debugger.  Make sure that your session cookie is actually being set on the ajax call.

Comment: session cookie value is not set at the first attempt but it's set at the second attempt.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?PHP
session_start();
include("DataBaseLogin.php");
if (isset($_SESSION['login']) && !empty($_SESSION['login']))
{
 header ("Location: page1.php");
}
else if($_SESSION['Level'] !=1 || empty($_SESSION['login'])) {
  header ("Location: index.php");
}
?>
```

Comment: This code will always redirect the authentic user to index.php.

Comment: Yes, then where you want to redirect the user after authentication ?

Comment: page1.php --> when user has successfully logged in.
index.php --> when user is not logged in.

Comment: Please explain what is wrong with OP's code and how that solves the problem *by editing your question.*

Comment: This will not redirect the page to the page1.php.

Answer (score 0):

try putting this at the end of your script:

```
session_write_close();
```

if you are using classes (for example, when using a framework controller), put it in the destruct function

```
function __destruct(){
     session_write_close();
}
```